# How to append Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I want to append Expression. I tried different solutions (available online) but unable to append. Here is my example.

```
Expression<Func<Consumer, bool>> e1 = c => c.CROID == CROID;
Expression<Func<Consumer, bool>> e2 = c => c.WorkFlow == WorkFlowIndexStr;
```

I want to add these two expression. Any help??

Comment: What do you mean by "append"? What *exactly* should the outcome be?

Comment: I have many attributes to compare with in same function.. but some attributes are in if blocks. If i don't append it i have to write whole scenario in each if block..